# Prevent TeX4ht from inserting img in equation with \mathcal

Tags: tex4ht, mathjax, mathml

When I use TeX4ht to produce MathML, it produces an image when I use `\mathcal` in the equation. The result is that MathJax complains that the code is not valid. Is there a way to fix this problem?

Minimal working example, to be compiled with `latex` and `tex4ht`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xhtml,mathml]{tex4ht}

\begin{document}
$\mathcal{L}$
\end{document}
```

The resulting html file contains

```
<mi mathvariant="bold-script">
  <img src="cmsy10-4c.png" alt="L" class="10x-x-4c" />
</mi>
```

How can I get rid of the `img` tag? And how come it is recognised as `bold-script`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please use the following command to generate mathml:

```
mzlatex <file> 'xhtml,mathml,charset=utf-8' ' -cunihtf'
```

Comment: Brilliant! What did it for me is to call `tex4ht` with the option `-cmozhtf` (I don't have `mzlatex` on my system, by I believe this is equivalent). Thanks a lot!

Comment: OK. In that case, you can call `htlatex` with the above options.

Comment: Uh... unfortunately, this breaks the calls to `\mathfrak`. That is, `\mathfrak{g}` now displays like a regular g, instead of fraktur. Is there a way to have both working?

Comment: I see, now it works, with the option `-cunihtf`. Thanks a lot!!!